# is it ok to use dynamic bind to implement polymorphism instead of pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, std-function, dynamic-binding

generally in c++ we use virtual class and pointers to achieve polymorphism, but recently I accidently made it with dynamic binding with std::function

sample:

```cpp
class base {
using func_t = std::function<void()>;
private:
    func_t func_;

public:
    void foo() {
        func_();
    }
    void set(func_t func) {
        func_ = std::move(func);
    } 
};

class derived : public base{
public:
    // something_else
};

void caller(base& b) {
    b.foo();
}

void test() {
    derived d;
    d.set([]() {
        printf("test\n");
    });
    caller(d);
}
```

this code would work, but is it safe? or just rely on the implementation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with polymorphism, and barely anything to do with dynamic binding. This is a caller-specified lambda that has nothing to with with `base` or `derived` being called from a member. Whether you did so from an instance of `derived` or `base` is irrelevant. The place where this falls apart (and thus, not-safe) is if no one ever invoked `set`, yet attempted to invoke `base::foo` anyway. But again, that has nothing to do with your derivation or polymorphism.

Comment: @WhozCraig so, I can pass a `derived`  variable as a `base` argument safely? I don't have to specify the `caller` as `void caller(base*)` ?

Comment: You're not passing a derived variable as a base argument; you're passing a derived variable to a callee expecting a *reference to* base argument, and since the derivation tree is intact, it's compliant. No slicing will ensue.

Comment: @WhozCraig thx, I got it, that would solve my confusion